# rowSums but keeping NA values

Tags: r, xts

I am pretty sure this is quite simple, but seem to have got stuck...I have two xts vectors that have been merged together, which contain numeric values and NAs.

I would like to get the rowSums for each index period, but keeping the NA values.

Below is a reproducible example

```
set.seed(120)
dd <- xts(rnorm(100),Sys.Date()-c(100:1))
dd1 <- ifelse(dd<(-0.5),dd*-1,NA)
dd2 <- ifelse((dd^2)>0.5,dd,NA)
mm <- merge(dd1,dd2)
mm$m <- rowSums(mm,na.rm=TRUE)
tail(mm,10)

                 dd1        dd2        m
2013-08-02        NA         NA 0.000000
2013-08-03        NA         NA 0.000000
2013-08-04        NA         NA 0.000000
2013-08-05 1.2542692 -1.2542692 0.000000
2013-08-06        NA  1.3325804 1.332580
2013-08-07        NA  0.7726740 0.772674
2013-08-08 0.8158402 -0.8158402 0.000000
2013-08-09        NA  1.2292919 1.229292
2013-08-10        NA         NA 0.000000
2013-08-11        NA  0.9334900 0.933490
```

In the above example on the 10th Aug 2013 I was hoping it would say `NA` instead of `0`, the same goes for the 2nd-4th Aug 2013.

Any suggestions for an elegant way of getting NAs in the relevant places?

Comment: Do a second pass where you check rows where `all(is.na(rowValues))` is `TRUE`, and set the values in those positions to `NA`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have a variable number of columns you could try this approach:

```
mm <- merge(dd1,dd2)
mm$m <- rowSums(mm, na.rm=TRUE) * ifelse(rowSums(is.na(mm)) == ncol(mm), NA, 1)
# or, as @JoshuaUlrich commented:
#mm$m <- ifelse(apply(is.na(mm),1,all),NA,rowSums(mm,na.rm=TRUE))
tail(mm, 10)
#                  dd1        dd2        m
#2013-08-02        NA         NA       NA
#2013-08-03        NA         NA       NA
#2013-08-04        NA         NA       NA
#2013-08-05 1.2542692 -1.2542692 0.000000
#2013-08-06        NA  1.3325804 1.332580
#2013-08-07        NA  0.7726740 0.772674
#2013-08-08 0.8158402 -0.8158402 0.000000
#2013-08-09        NA  1.2292919 1.229292
#2013-08-10        NA         NA       NA
#2013-08-11        NA  0.9334900 0.933490
```

Comment: A slightly different command: `mm$m <- ifelse(apply(is.na(mm),1,all),NA,rowSums(mm,na.rm=TRUE))`

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I like your solution best...nice and neat/elegant...so if you want to make it a full answer I will put the tick next to that...

Comment: @h.l.m it's the same concept; I'll just edit it into this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use logical indexing with `[` and `is.na(·)` to localize the entries where both are `NA` and then replace them with `NA`.

Try this:

```
> mm[is.na(mm$dd1) & is.na(mm$dd2), "m"] <- NA
> mm
                 dd1        dd2        m
2013-08-02        NA         NA       NA
2013-08-03        NA         NA       NA
2013-08-04        NA         NA       NA
2013-08-05 1.2542692 -1.2542692 0.000000
2013-08-06        NA  1.3325804 1.332580
2013-08-07        NA  0.7726740 0.772674
2013-08-08 0.8158402 -0.8158402 0.000000
2013-08-09        NA  1.2292919 1.229292
2013-08-10        NA         NA       NA
2013-08-11        NA  0.9334900 0.933490
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mm$m <- "is.na<-"(rowSums(mm, na.rm = TRUE), !rowSums(!is.na(mm)))

> tail(mm)
#                  dd1        dd2        m
# 2013-08-06        NA  1.3325804 1.332580
# 2013-08-07        NA  0.7726740 0.772674
# 2013-08-08 0.8158402 -0.8158402 0.000000
# 2013-08-09        NA  1.2292919 1.229292
# 2013-08-10        NA         NA       NA
# 2013-08-11        NA  0.9334900 0.933490
```

Comment: While this works, it's certain to confuse almost all people who look at your code.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be

```
library(magrittr)
mm <- mm %>% 
      transform(ccardNA = rowSums(!is.na(.))/rowSums(!is.na(.)), m = rowSums(., na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
      transform(m = ifelse(is.nan(ccardNA), NA, m), ccardNA = NULL) %>%
      as.xts()
```