# rowSums with all NA

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 1, NA, 0, 1, 0),
                 b = c(0, 1, NA, NA, 0, 1),
                 c = c(NA, 0, NA, 0, 1, NA),
                 d = c(1, NA, NA, 1, 1, 0))

rowSums(df)
#[1] NA NA NA NA  3 NA
rowSums(df, na.rm=T)
#[1] 2 2 0 1 3 1
```

The first I get, but my assumption and hope was that the third observation would return `NA`. Is there a way to get it to return NA for the third observation?

Comment: See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189753/rowsums-but-keeping-na-values (multiply by an `ifelse`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
rowSums(df, na.rm = TRUE) * NA ^ (rowSums(!is.na(df)) == 0)
# [1]  2  2 NA  1  3  1
```

This uses that `anything ^ 0` equals 1 in R.

Answer (score 1):

not the best solution, but

```
a<-rowSums(df,na.rm=T)
a[a==0 & is.na(rowSums(df))]<-NA
```

should work

Comment: and what about columns with zeroes? you could not distinguish them from NA columns!

Comment: You could do `a[rowSums(!is.na(df)) == 0] <- NA` instead

Comment: a column with zeroes shouldn't be transferred as is.na(rowSums(df)) equals F. Or have I overlooked a problem?