# rowSums does not into account recodes inside same mutate statement

Tags: r, dplyr

I have written two functions:

```
count_na_row <- function(., vars = NULL){
  
  if(is.null(vars)){
    rowSums(is.na(.))
  } else {
    rowSums(is.na(select(., vars)))
  }
  
}

count_na_row_where <- function(., .fun = NULL){
  
  if(is.null(.fun)){
    warning('.fun is NULL. No function is applied. Counts NAs on all columns')
    rowSums(is.na(.))
  } else {
    rowSums(is.na(select(., where(.fun))))
  }
}
```

The functions are applied as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- 
  tibble(
    var1 = c(1, 2, NA, 1, 3, NA, 1, 7),
    var2 = c(NA, 3, 1, 3, NA, 9, NA, 4),
    varstr = c("A", "B", "", "", 'F', 'C', 'A', "M")
  )

df %>% 
  mutate(
    na_count = count_na_row(.),
    na_count_str = count_na_row_where(., is.character)
  )
```

My trouble is that the functions does not take into account NA values that are recoded inside the same mutate statement:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    varstr = ifelse(varstr == "", NA, varstr),
    na_count = count_na_row(.),
    na_count_str = count_na_row_where(., is.character),
    na_count_num = count_na_row_where(., is.numeric)
  )
```

But if I recode in a separate, preceeding mutate statement, it works:

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    varstr = ifelse(varstr == "", NA, varstr)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    na_count = count_na_row(.),
    na_count_str = count_na_row_where(., is.character),
    na_count_num = count_na_row_where(., is.numeric)
  )
```

How can I adapt the functions so that I can recode into NA values inside the same mutate statement? I suspect the issues lies with `rowSums`.

Comment: Maybe this could help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33672059/rowsums-with-all-na

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working as intended. It doesn't have to do with `rowSums` as much as it has to do with the `.` operator.

From the `magittr` documentation we can find:

> Placing lhs elsewhere in rhs call
>
> Often you will want lhs to the rhs
> call at another position than the first. For this purpose you can use
> the dot (.) as placeholder. For example, y %>% f(x, .) is equivalent
> to f(x, y) and z %>% f(x, y, arg = .) is equivalent to f(x, y, arg =
> z).

What is important here is that `.` refers to the LHS. When you structure your pipeline like this:

```
df %>%
  mutate(x = ...,
         y = rowSums(.))
```

The LHS will still be `df`, as that is the code before the last `%>%`. If you want to take into account the mutated `x` you will have to put that in the LHS using nested mutations like so:

```
df %>%
  mutate(x = ...) %>%
  mutate(y = rowSums(.))
```