# simplifying R code using dplyr (or other) to rowSums while ignoring NA, unlss all is NA

Tags: r, dplyr, code-cleanup, rowsum

I've initially solved my NA-issue helped by [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18190153/1305688). However, I would like to simplify my code. In the past, I've enjoyed the way [dplyr](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) has helped me simplify R code.

Below is a minimal working example illustrating my current solution and where I am at with dplyr.

I have data like this,

```
dta <- data.frame(foo=c(1,NA,3,4), fooZ=c(4,NA,5,NA), fooQ2=c(7,0,9,NA))
```

I need to summarize quite a few rows, using 0 as *a value* that I *sum* and keeping `NA`'s for rows with all `NA`. Like this,

```
dta$sum1 <- rowSums(dta[, c('fooZ', 'fooQ2') ], na.rm=TRUE) * ifelse(
      rowSums(is.na(dta[, c('fooZ', 'fooQ2') ])) == 
               ncol(dta[, c('fooZ', 'fooQ2') ]), NA, 1)
dta
# >   foo fooZ fooQ2 sum1
# > 1   1    4     7   11
# > 2  NA   NA     0    0
# > 3   3    5     9   14
# > 4   4   NA    NA   NA
```

This does the trick and creates `sum1`, but I have to repeat the reference to the data three times. Can I simplify this in some handy way? I've made the below code using dplyr, but maybe there's a better way of summarizing rows; while keeping `NA` for rows that have all `NA`, ignoring `NA`'s in rows with one or more values, and treating 0 a value to be 'summarized'?

```
# install.packages(c("dplyr", "ggplot2"), dependencies = TRUE)
require(dplyr)
dta$sum2 = dta %>% select(fooZ, fooQ2) %>% rowSums(., na.rm = TRUE)
dta
# >   foo fooZ fooQ2 sum1 sum2
# > 1   1    4     7   11   11
# > 2  NA   NA     0    0    0
# > 3   3    5     9   14   14
# > 4   4   NA    NA   NA    0
```

This creates `sum2`, but generates a 0 if `na.rm = TRUE` and too many `NA`'s if  `na.rm = F`.

### Update as of 16 22:18:33Z

I made this somewhat elaborate *micro*-benchmark comparison of the different answer. Please feel do not haste to optimize any of the function. Writing R functions is not my force. Regardless,

```
set.seed(667)
n <- 1e5+22
dta <- data.frame(
  foo = sample(c(1:10, NA), n, replace = TRUE),
  fooZ = sample(c(1:10, NA), n, replace = TRUE),
  fooQ2 = sample(c(1:10, NA), n, replace = TRUE))

slice <- c(902:907,979:984)
dta[slice,]
#>     foo fooZ fooQ2
#> 902  10    7     2
#> 903  10   10     9
#> 904  NA   NA     8
#> 905   6    4     3
#> 906   8    9    10
#> 907   1    5    NA
#> 979  NA    1     1
#> 980  10    2    NA
#> 981   7   NA    NA
#> 982   3    7     7
#> 983  NA    9     6
#> 984   7   10     7


# `baseline' solution
baseline <- function(z, ...) {W  <- z[, c(...)]; W <- rowSums(W, na.rm=TRUE) * ifelse(rowSums(is.na(W)) == ncol(W), NA, 1); W}

# install.packages(c("dplyr", "ggplot2"), dependencies = TRUE)
require(dplyr)
# G. G.Gro's dplyr solution
G.Gro_dplyr1 <- function(z, ...) z %>% mutate(sum2 = select(., ...) %>% { rowSums(., na.rm = TRUE) + ifelse(apply(is.na(.), 1, all), NA, 0) })

# G. G.Gro's Variation 1a solution
G.Gro_dplyr1a <- function(z, ...) z %>% mutate(sum2 = select(., fooZ, fooQ2) %>% apply(1, . %>% { sum(., na.rm = TRUE) + if (all(is.na(.))) NA else 0}))

# G. G.Gro's base solution
G.Gro_base <- function(z, ...) {W  <- z[, c(...)]; S = {X <- dta[, c("fooZ", "fooQ2")]; rowSums(X, na.rm = TRUE) + ifelse(apply(is.na(X), 1, all), NA, 0)}; S}

# Thierry's solution
Thierry_my_sum <- function(z, ...){z <- select(z, ...); sums <- rowSums(z, na.rm = TRUE); sums[apply(is.na(z), 1, all)] <- NA; sums}

# lmo's solution
lmo <- function(z, ...) {W  <- z[, c(...)]; rowSums(W, na.rm=TRUE) * (NA^(rowSums(is.na(W)) == ncol(W)))}

# Benjamin's solution
Benjamin <- function(..., na.rm = FALSE, all.na = NA){v <- list(...); all_na <- lapply(v, is.na); all_na <- Reduce(`&`, all_na); all_na; if (na.rm){v <- lapply(v, function(x) {x[is.na(x)] <- 0; x}); }; v <- Reduce(`+`, v); v[all_na] <- all.na; v;}

# Aramis7d's solution
Aramis7d <- function(z, ...) {z %>% select(...) %>% mutate(sum = rowSums(., na.rm=TRUE)) %>% mutate(s2 = rowSums(is.na(.))) %>% mutate(sum = if_else(s2 < 2, sum, as.double(NA))) %>%  select(sum) }

# Fail's solution combining from all
Fail <- function(z, ...){z <- select(z, ...); zTF <- rowMeans(is.na(z)) == 1; replace(rowSums(z, na.rm = TRUE), zTF, NA)}

# install.packages("microbenchmark", dependencies = TRUE)
require(microbenchmark)

# run test
res <- microbenchmark(
baseline(dta, c("fooZ", "fooQ2")),
Thierry_my_sum(dta, fooZ, fooQ2),
G.Gro_dplyr1(dta, fooZ, fooQ2)[,ncol(dta)+1],
G.Gro_dplyr1a(dta, fooZ, fooQ2)[, ncol(dta) + 1],
G.Gro_base(dta, c("fooZ", "fooQ2")),
(dta %>% mutate(sum99 = Benjamin(fooZ, fooQ2, na.rm = TRUE)))[,ncol(dta)+1],
lmo(dta, c("fooZ", "fooQ2")),
Aramis7d(dta, fooZ, fooQ2)[,1],
Fail(dta, fooZ, fooQ2),
 times = 25)

# clean up
levels(res[[1]]) <- c('baseline', 'Thierry', 'G.Gro1', 'G.Gro1a', 'G.Gro2', 'Benjamin', 'lmo', 'Aramis7d', 'Fail')

## Print results:
print(res)

 print(res)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>      expr        min         lq        mean     median          uq        max neval cld
#>  baseline  12.729803  15.691060   31.141114  23.299101   48.694436   72.83702    25   a  
#>   Thierry 215.541035 241.795764  298.319826 263.822553  363.066476  494.90875    25   b 
#>    G.Gro1 226.761181 242.617099  295.413437 264.911513  307.339115  591.28424    25   b 
#>   G.Gro1a 935.176542 985.329298 1088.300741 997.788858 1030.085839 1736.51506    25   c
#>    G.Gro2 219.650080 227.464694  292.898566 246.188189  320.789036  505.08154    25   b 
#>  Benjamin   6.227054   9.327364   15.583907  11.230079   14.345366   55.44653    25   a  
#>       lmo   4.138434   5.970850    9.329506   6.851132    8.406799   39.40295    25   a  
#>  Aramis7d  33.966101  38.737671   60.777304  66.663967   72.686939  100.72799    25   a  
#>      Fail  11.464254  13.932386   20.476011  14.865245   25.156740   58.37730    25   a  

### Plot results:
boxplot(res)
```

[image: box-]

Comment: Shouldn't the fourth value of sum1 be 4? or maybe you want to remove 4 from row foo?

Comment: In general, if you are using `rowSums`, you will have to fight with `dplyr` since it is designed for column wise operations. The general tidy way is to `gather`, `group_by` and then `sum`.

Comment: @imo, I am only summing `fooZ` and `fooQ2`, as they are both `NA` the result should be `NA'. I am not using `foo` for now.

Comment: @Axeman, I really appreciate your feedback. Any chance you could show me how or point me to an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a base R trick using exponentiation of NA:

```
rowSums(dta[-1], na.rm=TRUE) * (NA^(rowSums(is.na(dta[-1])) == ncol(dta[-1])))
[1] 11  8 14 NA
```

Any number to the 0th power is 1, so any rows that contain a non-NA value return a 1 in the second term. Otherwise, NA is returned.

This assumes that you only want to take into account variables other than your first variable.

Combining the improvements the OP made to the code above with an additional step, we could improve the efficiency with

```
rowSumsNA <- function(dat, ...) {
    W <- data.matrix(dat[...])
    rowSums(W, na.rm=TRUE) * (NA^(rowSums(is.na(W)) == ncol(W)))
}
```

Most of the improvements are in the OP's method of storing the subset data.frame prior to the calculation (127ms vs 84ms on my machine), but a slight additional improvement can be had by converting that data.frame to a matrix prior to calling `rowSums` (84ms vs 77ms on my machine).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I need to make an explicit reference to the variable names as they are at shifting positions in data. In addition, I note your solution too makes _reference_ to data three times.

Comment: I’ve made a _microbenchmark_ comparison of the different answers. Please forgive me if I totally butchered your answer in rewriting it to a function. If so please feel free to improve on what I did! Thanks again for your contribution.

Comment: @EricFail This seems like an accurate depiction of my suggestion along with the couple of improvements I would have implemented. The only additional improvement would be to directly convert w to a matrix in the first step: `W  <- data.matrix(z[, c(...)])`. This is because `rowSums` will convert a data.frame to a matrix, so we might as well do it up front to save the two conversions.

Answer (score 2):

**1) dplyr** This computes the row sums and then adds on NA or 0 depending on whether the entire row is NA or not.

```
dta %>%
    mutate(sum2 = select(., fooZ, fooQ2) %>%
                  { rowSums(., na.rm = TRUE) + ifelse(apply(is.na(.), 1, all), NA, 0) })
```

giving:

```
  foo fooZ fooQ2 sum2
1   1    4     7   11
2  NA   NA     8    8
3   3    5     9   14
4   4   NA    NA   NA
```

**1a) Variation**  A variation of (1) is:

```
dta %>%
    mutate(sum2 = select(., fooZ, fooQ2) %>%
        apply(1, . %>% { sum(., na.rm = TRUE) + if (all(is.na(.))) NA else 0}))
```

**2) base** Using no packages we can do this:

```
transform(dta, sum2 = { 
      X <- data.frame(fooZ, fooQ2)
      rowSums(X, na.rm = TRUE) + ifelse(apply(is.na(X), 1, all), NA, 0)
})
```

**3) data.table**

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(dta)
DT[, sum2 := rowSums(.SD, na.rm = TRUE) + ifelse(apply(is.na(.SD), 1, all), NA, 0) , .SDcols = c("fooZ", "fooQ2")]
```

**Update:** Moved select inside mutate to preserve foo column.  Added additional solutions.

Comment: Thanks. I like the relative simplicity of your solution.

Comment: In other comments, @EricFail states a preference for not dropping too many variables.  Your current code loses the `foo` variable.  It might be worthwhile to add `%>% select(sum2) %>% bind_cols(dta, .)` to the answer to generate an exact match of the expected output

Comment: @Benjamin, I appreciate your input! I am just now working to rewrite this solution to get rid of the `mutate' and get only the new sum.

Comment: OK. I have moved the select inside the mutate.

Comment: I’ve made a _microbenchmark_ comparison of the different answers. Please forgive me if I totally butchered your answers in the comparison. If so please feel free to improve on what I did! Thanks again for your many contributions.

Comment: Have added a data.table solution.

Comment: Did you run it though the `microbenchmark` comparison?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple dplyr solution

```
library(dplyr)
dta <- data.frame(foo=c(1,NA,3,4), fooZ=c(4,NA,5,NA), fooQ2=c(7,0,9,NA))
my_sum <- function(z, ...){
  z <- select(z, ...)
  sums <- rowSums(z, na.rm = TRUE)
  sums[apply(is.na(z), 1, all)] <- NA
  sums
}

dta %>%
  mutate(
    sum1 = my_sum(., fooZ, fooQ2),
    sum2 = my_sum(., foo, fooQ2),
    sum3 = my_sum(., foo, fooZ)
  )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe writing a function is the way to go. Is there a simple way to remove the `mutate` to solely produce the sum vector and not a full new data frame? Kinda like the thinking in my initial solution-attempt?

Comment: sure. `my_sum(dta, fooZ, fooQ2)`

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks! Now for the benchmarking in the wild.

Comment: I’ve made a _microbenchmark_ comparison of the different answers. Please forgive me if I totally butchered your function in the comparison. If so please feel free to improve on what I did! Thanks again for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Not as elegant as the other solutions, but it avoids having to drop variables from the data frame and then rejoin. So this is good if you're interested in keeping your data frame intact.  It will lose it's advantage if you have a lot of variables to include.

```
dta %>% 
  mutate(all_na = Reduce(`&`, lapply(list(fooZ, fooQ2), is.na)),
         sum1 = Reduce(`+`, lapply(list(fooZ, fooQ2), function(x) {x[is.na(x)] <- 0; x})),
         sum1 = ifelse(all_na, NA, sum1)) %>% 
  select(-all_na)
```

Alternatively, you can bundle it into a function:

```
rsum <- function(..., na.rm = FALSE, all.na = NA){

  v <- list(...)

  all_na <- lapply(v, is.na)
  all_na <- Reduce(`&`, all_na)
  all_na

  if (na.rm){
    v <- lapply(v, function(x) {x[is.na(x)] <- 0; x})
  }

  v <- Reduce(`+`, v)

  v[all_na] <- all.na
  v
}

dta %>% 
  mutate(sum1 = rsum(fooZ, fooQ2, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Thing is I do have a lot of variables to include, and I need to do this a lot. Hence my interest in finding something simple where I reference data and variables as few times as possible. While not creating or dropping too many variables either.

Comment: I’ve made a _microbenchmark_ comparison of the different answers. Please forgive me if I totally butchered your function in the comparison. If so please feel free to improve on what I did! Thanks again for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

alternately, using `dplyr`, you can try something like:

```
dta %>%
  select(-foo) %>%
  mutate(sum1 = rowSums(., na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(s2 = rowSums(is.na(.))) %>%  
  mutate(sum1 = if_else(s2 < 2, sum1, as.double(NA))) %>%
  bind_cols(dta) %>%
  select(foo, fooZ, fooQ2, sum1)
```

which gives:

```
  foo fooZ fooQ2 sum1
1   1    4     7   11
2  NA   NA     8    8
3   3    5     9   14
4   4   NA    NA   NA
```

in case you don't really care about retaining the column `foo` , you can get rid of the `col_bind` fucntion call

Comment: I’ve made a _microbenchmark_ comparison of the different answers. Please forgive me if I butchered your answer in making a function out of it. If so please feel free to improve on what I did! Thanks again for your contribution.