# Any suggestions to implement filter within mutate using dplyr or rowsums with all missing cases

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr, rowsum

Psychologists work with likert scales almost all the time and let's say I have this dataset:

```
data <- data.frame(x1 = c(NA,2,4),
                   x2 = c(NA,3,2),
                   x3 = c(NA,6,NA))
```

I would like to use RowSums only if X1, X2, and X3 are not missing.

This won't work because it will not consider any variable with missing cases:

```
data %>%
  mutate(total_score = rowSums(select(.,x1:x3), na.rm=F))
```

And this will not work neither:

```
data %>%
  filter_at(vars(x1:x2), any_vars(!is.na(.))) %>% 
  mutate(total_score = rowSums(select(.,x1:x3), na.rm=T))
```

Because it will filter my dataset and then reduce the number of observations.

Therefore, I would like to integrate filter within mutate.

I have read a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189753/rowsums-but-keeping-na-values) before this one, but I was not able to implement it.

ps: I would like to keep in tidyverse environment. 
Thank you

My code:

```
data <- data.frame(x1 = c(NA,2,4),
                   x2 = c(NA,3,2),
                   x3 = c(NA,6,NA))


data %>%
  mutate(total_score = rowSums(select(.,x1:x3), na.rm=F))

data %>%
  filter_at(vars(x1:x2), any_vars(!is.na(.))) %>% 
  mutate(total_score = rowSums(select(.,x1:x3), na.rm=T))
```

Comment: What is the wrong with using `data %>% mutate(total_score = rowSums(select(.,x1:x3), na.rm=F))` ? It will give `NA` if there is even a single `NA` and sum your data only if all  values are not `NA`. Isn't that what you want? What is your expected output?

Comment: This post was some time ago. My goal at that moment was to not produce the `total_score` when all values were missing.  Thank you for your interest !!

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```r
data <- data.frame(x1 = c(NA,2,4),
                   x2 = c(NA,3,2),
                   x3 = c(NA,6,NA))
mutate(data, tmp = x1+x2+x3)
```

If you are committed to using the `rowSums` function then one option is to `coalesce` first:

```r
data %>%
  mutate_all(~{coalesce(.,-1000)}) %>% # replace all NA with -1000
  mutate(total_score = rowSums(select(.,x1:x3), na.rm=F)) %>%
  mutate_all(~{ifelse(.<0,NA,.)}) # replace any negative numbers with NA
```

Coalesce is a dplyr function that returns the first non-NA value. The idea here is that if we carry our a row-sum after replacing all NAs with large negative numbers, then any negatives in the result must have come from NAs. Of course this assumes all your input values are non-negative.

In case it is unfamiliar the `~{.}` pattern is used for anonymous functions. So `~{coalesce(.,-1000)}` is equivalent to `function(x){coalesce(x,-1000)}`

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, as this solution replaces the missing cases with -1000, I cannot get the total score in the way I want. The first row and the third row became "NA". I think was not clear in my question. Sorry. My goal is to sum x1, x2, and x3 only if x1 and x2 and x3 (together) are not missing.  If X1 is missing (but X2 and X3 are not), I would like to sum, etc. Thank you

Comment: So then hat about replacing the -1000 with 0 in the first `mutate_all` and replacing `<0` with `==0` in the second `mutate_all`?

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to fix it based on your suggestion! =)